# Why am i limited to using Intrepid and lower as an Ubuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization

I've been trying to install KVM on Ubuntu 11 64bit now. I've been following the [docs from the Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation) site and everything is going well. I've reached the point where I need to build my VM and it said that I could execute this `sudo ubuntu-vm-builder kvm inteprid to create the VM.

Why is that Intrepid is the latest version available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 11.04 output of `ubuntu-vm-builder kvm ubuntu --help` shows following:

```
--suite=SUITE       Suite to install. Valid options: dapper gutsy hardy
                    intrepid jaunty karmic lucid maverick natty [default:
                    lucid]
```

So I don't think it is limited to **intrepid**.

Comment: Seems like I've been relying on the docs too much. Does this install the desktop or the server version? Sorry if it sounds silly but I'm new to this.

Comment: Well, community docs could be more outdated than packaged docs. With regards to desktop or server version I recommend opening separate question.